# iterate through a string[] List<string> fetch results alphabetically

Tags: c#, linq, list, arrays

I will first declare the main question here so you can skip the rest if you like.

**How do I make result list sorted alphabetically?**

```
public static List<string> GenerateMonthNames(string prefixText)
{
    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    items.Add("a");
    items.Add("appl");
    items.Add("ap");
    items.Add("apple");
    items.Add("change");
    items.Add("world");
    items.Add("engaging");

    string[] strArray = items.ToArray();

    string tempFundstr = string.Empty;
    List<string> returnedList= new List<string>();

    int strNumber;
    int strIndex = 0;
    for (strNumber = 0; strNumber < strArray.Length; strNumber++)
    {
        strIndex = strArray[strNumber].IndexOf(prefixText);
        if (strIndex >= 0)
        {
            tempFoundStr = strArray[strNumber];
            retLst.Add(retstr);
        }    
    }

    items.Clear();
    return returnedList;
}
```

it was desperate try on Ajax `autoComplete` just...to get it working, without using Database as source for the autoComplete data

though I have solved main issue, as it wasn't working at all (;. and now after "fixing" the problem the autoComplete does work. **but**

it's kind'a messy solution I have manage to pull in order to iterate through the list or an array  the problem here is that I can't understand how,  by using Linq, enumerate or any implementation so i will be able to  return the result list **sorted alphabetically**.

And with your help, i hope to get the code straight (by the book).

Comment: skip the ToArray first of all.

2nd is it just the Sort() method you're looking for or what?

then it's just items.Sort()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static List<string> GenerateMonthNames(string prefixText)    
{
    var items = new List<string>();
    items.Add("Oliver");
    items.Add("Olsen");
    items.Add("learns");
    items.Add("how");
    items.Add("change");
    items.Add("world");
    items.Add("engaging");  

    var returnList = items.Where(item=>item.Contains(prefixTest)).ToList();
    returnList.Sort();

    return returnList;
}
```

Comment: thanks man ! i didn't see your reply ...at first glance i was mistaking it for being a part of my question (: seems that you are the first(checked again now, you were actually second) to reply by the time indication and so i see you really knew what I was asking to come up with as my code suggests i am far from a professional developer and i like to learn coding the appropriate usage of .net methods and such . i really thank you and your quick and professional answer , although i haven't tested it yet , i will inform you upon a success. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
items.Where(item => item.IndexOf(prefixText) >= 0).OrderBy(item => item)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is simply returning a sorted list that you want to add, then this should work

```
return retLst.OrderBy(item=>item);
```

For a more complete refactoring, fo with PHeiberg's solution.

Also you can initialise like this

```
List<string> items = new List<string>(){"a", "appl", ...etc};
```

Comment: that's what i was looking for i think ! , but you see my code, i don't have do decide it could be either `List<string>` or string[] i think Ajax will take any result , so my question is how , by looking at my code realizing i am a nub , did i scratch my right ear with my left hand kind of analogue here , by using a list twice etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter all items which have prefix is `prefixText`, `StartWith` would be more corrective:

```
items.Where(item => item.StartsWith(prefixText))
     .OrderBy(item => item)
```

Comment: your method suppose to be even sharper than contatins i think ,logically , though i was asking(i know it was a little too much) to strip the code from an unwanted lines. i thank you for sharing your knowlage Cunog Le ! have a nice day !

Comment: i get an error items.Where(item => item.StartsWith(prefixText) >= 0).OrderBy(item => item);Error 16
 `Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'`

Comment: thanks for sharpenning the sort method . i will give it a check on both contain and start with , i guess when you think about both sides of the coin , start with is faster match , though contains let's you type any section of complete string so it's up to you to deside if you want to give the user the option to type.. say "pp" for apple which i guess will compute abit slower but would be less restricted to a surten rule , so you will deside what is your policy for the target text box . thanks again !